# How to get focal length of virtual pinhole camera in opengl

Tags: opengl, camera, camera-calibration, calibration

I have created a virtual dataset in OpenGL, so that I can get exact camera coordinates in relation to my target scene. I am running tests on stereo vision with two viewpoints of my scene, and trying to confirm that my epipoles are correct. However I need a calibration matrix for my virtual camera.

The principal points are easy since ideally it is just the resolution/2. But the focal length fx and fy (which ideally would be the same) are more difficult to establish.

This is an example of my scene from two different views:[image]

Left image:

- Camera coords in xyz wrt to world coords [ 0 0 3]
- looking at world coords [0 0 0]

Right image:

- Camera coords in xyz wrt to world coords [ 1 0 3]
- looking at world coords [0 0 0]

OpenGL camera perspective setup:

- Field of View = 45.0 degrees
- Aspect ratio 4:3

**How do I determine the Focal Length of this camera?**

Any ideas?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focal_length) states: "FOV = 2 arctan (x / (2f))". This should allow you to calculate the required data.

Comment: This post explains well how to overtake camera calibration parameters to OpenGL http://ksimek.github.io/2013/06/03/calibrated_cameras_in_opengl/